# Add element to table by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one table with a row. And I want to add the column to the row with the possible condition of my script with jquery. This is my sample code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function loadContent() {
    var $parent = $("#productlist").empty(); //empty div
    $parent.append('<br /><table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="productlist" style="margin-left:4px; padding-top:2px;"><tbody></tbody></table>');
    if (k % 3 == 0 && k == 0) {
        var $table = $parent.find("#myTable > tbody");
        var htmlRow = [
                      '<tr align="center">',
                      '<td align="center" id="colunm-product">',
                       //some data
                       '</td>'];
        $table.append(htmlRow.join(''));
    } else if ((k % 3 == 0) && (k != 0)) {
       //add more <td>
    } else {
       //close </tr>
    }
</script>
```

Can I create `<tr>` and add more `<td>`, when in the possible condition , I will append `</tr>`?

Any comment please?

Comment: where is `k` and what is its initial value?

Comment: It is my condition, but what I want to do is adding the `<tr>` and then close it with the condition. Can I open tag `<tr>` without close it immediately?

Comment: before opening a new `tr`, you need to close previous one

Comment: But when I did that, it closed the `<tr><td>any data </td></tr><td>any data</td>`.

Comment: you want to close you `tr` in third condition.. right?

Comment: yeah yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var htmlRow = [];
if (k % 3 == 0 && k == 0) {
    var $table = $parent.find("#myTable > tbody");
   htmlRow.push(
       '<tr align="center">',
       '<td align="center" id="colunm-product">some data</td>');
    } else if ((k % 3 == 0) && (k != 0)) {
        htmlRow.push('<td align="center" id="colunm-product-2">Data 1</td>',
                     '<td align="center" id="colunm-product-3">Data 2</td>',
                     '<td align="center" id="colunm-product-2">Data 3</td>');
    } else {
        htmlRow.push('</tr>');
        $table.append(htmlRow.join(''));
    }
```

OR you string concatenation

```
var htmlRow = '';
if (k % 3 == 0 && k == 0) {
    var $table = $parent.find("#myTable > tbody");
    htmlRow += '<tr align="center">'+
                '<td align="center" id="colunm-product">some data</td>';
} else if ((k % 3 == 0) && (k != 0)) {
    htmlRow +=
        '<td align="center" id="colunm-product-2">Data 1</td>'+
        '<td align="center" id="colunm-product-3">Data 2</td>'+
        '<td align="center" id="colunm-product-2">Data 3</td>';
} else {
    htmlRow += '</tr>';
    $table.append(htmlRow);
}
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/503/)**

Comment: @thecodeparadox...  you can't append a closing tag fragment, row has to be closed before first append, is clearly stated in API

Comment: @socheata check my update answer, you have to make little change like above and you can achieve your goal

Comment: you should have the `htmlRow` outside of the `if-else` clause, otherwise it'll be undefined in 2nd & 3rd condition

Comment: Why the `k % 3 == 0 && k == 0`? Would saying `k == 0` not be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should construct the row as a jQuery object, then append additional `<td>` if required.

then finally append the row to the table.

```
if (k % 3 == 0) {
  var $table = $parent.find("#myTable > tbody");
  // htmlRow as jQuery object.
  var htmlRow = $([
    '<tr align="center">',
       '<td align="center" id="colunm-product">',
           //some data
       '</td>',
    '</tr>'].join('')
   );

  if(k != 0) {
    htmlRow.append([
       '<td>',
        // More Data
       '</td>'
       ].join(''));
  }

  // Add completed row here
  $table.append(htmlRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I wrote that, the result is `[object Object]`.